# syntax error on functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, syntax-error

When I add this to the end of my theme function.php I get a syntax error on the last line, how do I fix this?

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is incomplete.  You never closed the `add_action()` function call:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    //...
}); // <--- Need to close the function call and end the statement with a semi-colon
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket and semicolon (the `);` part):

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
});
```